# How to launch Youtube application to open a playlist?

Tags: android, adb

I want to open my YouTube playlist link in YouTube Android app, if YouTube app is installed on the device.
I try code bellow but not true.
Please help me

```
adb - s emulator - 5554 shell am start - a android.intent.action.VIEW - d \"vnd.youtube:/playlist/PL8mjSseObLTkEzNIGXqip-_NtkfDJM-Kk\" com.google.android.youtube
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the `adb` command to use in order to launch the Youtube app showing the playlist provided as adb parameter:

```
adb -s emulator-5554 shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "vnd.youtube:playlist/PL8mjSseObLTkEzNIGXqip-_NtkfDJM-Kk"
```

Comment: @LotusMedia does the answer above help to figure out the issue?