# Is it possible to run android apk on ubuntu as headless emulator

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, android-emulator, command-line-interface

I want to install chrome and youtube apk as headless android emulator on ubuntu. Also want to run apk in headless mode.

Is it possible? anbox have gui, i wanting headless.

Answer (score 2):

To run Android emulator in headless mode you have to use the `-no-audio` and `-no-window` flags.

Example:

```
~/Android/Sdk/emulator/emulator -avd Pixel_2_API_30 -no-audio -no-window
```

To install an application you can use `adb install appname.apk`.

To open an activity use `adb shell am start`. There are already some answers about that both for [Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28151563/771431) and [YouTube](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68701598/771431).

Comment: I will try and  update you